# Create a list based on value in column pandas with exceptions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add into a list value of `COL2` only if `COL1` value is unique (there is only one matching with a `COL1` value).

```
List_lonely_sequences=[]
```

Here is the dataframe

```
COL1 COL2
SP1  SEQA
SP1  SEQB
SP1  SEQC
SP2  SEQC
SP2  SEQD
SP3  SEQA
SP4  SEQB
SP4  SEQD
SP5  SEQL
SP6  SEQL
```

My list (`List_lonely_sequences`) should include `SEQA` because it is the only sequence matching with `SP3`. 
My list should also include `SEQL` because it is the only sequence matching with `SP5` and `SP6`.

The expected result would be :

```py
List_lonely_sequences = ['SEQA','SEQL']
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
unique_vals = df.drop_duplicates(['COL1'], keep=False)['COL2'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to group by the first column, and aggregate as a list

```
   grouped = df.groupby('COL1').agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

Then you need to look for lists with only 1 element, and extract the values.
We then convert to a set to remove duplicates, and back to a list.

```
list(set(grouped[grouped.COL2.apply(len) == 1].COL2.apply(lambda x: x[0]).values))
```

Comment: I wont remove my answer, but the one above by Anshul is a much better solution!